# CS8620 IEnumerable differences in the nullability of reference types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For this code:

```
private ConcurrentBag<QueuedRequest> requests; 

...
            var request = this.requests.FirstOrDefault();
            this.requests = new ConcurrentBag<QueuedRequest>(this.requests.Except(new[] { request }));

#pragma warning disable VSTHRD110 // Observe result of async calls
            Task.Run(() =>
#pragma warning restore VSTHRD110 // Observe result of async calls
            {
                // get notifications for report id
                var reportId = GetReportId(request);
```

I am getting:
CS8620  Argument of type 'IEnumerable<QueuedRequest?>' cannot be used for parameter 'collection' of type 'IEnumerable' in 'ConcurrentBag.ConcurrentBag(IEnumerable collection)' due to differences in the nullability of reference types.

Offending line:

```
            this.requests = new ConcurrentBag<QueuedRequest>(this.requests.Except(new[] { request }));
```

Since `QueuedRequest` can be null, therefore `var request` can be null.

The warning is on the code `this.requests.Except(new[] { request })`, and I tried:

```
this.requests = new ConcurrentBag<QueuedRequest?>(this.requests.Except(new[] { request }));
```

but I got the same warning.
How can we change the code to resolve the warning? 
Thanks.

Edit #1 - @Matthew Watson since this class depends on several other classes, and I could not find a way to import then in the link you provided, the best I can do is to cut out the lines that are irrevalent:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/mOLjvZ

As you can see adding ? to the collection results in the same error.  Screenshot: 
[image]

Edit #2

```
    {
#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field is uninitialized. Consider declaring as nullable.
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets execution request.
        /// </summary>
        public ExecutionRequest ExecutionRequest { get; set; }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field is uninitialized. Consider declaring as nullable.

#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field is uninitialized. Consider declaring as nullable.
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets execution token.
        /// </summary>
        public ExecutionToken ExecutionToken { get; set; }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field is uninitialized. Consider declaring as nullable.
    }
```

```
    public class ConcurrentBag<T> : IProducerConsumerCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, ICollection, IReadOnlyCollection<T>
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1
        //     class.
        public ConcurrentBag();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1
        //     class that contains elements copied from the specified collection.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   collection:
        //     The collection whose elements are copied to the new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   T:System.ArgumentNullException:
        //     collection is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic).
        public ConcurrentBag(IEnumerable<T> collection);

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the number of elements contained in the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The number of elements contained in the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.
        public int Count { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets a value that indicates whether the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1
        //     is empty.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1 is empty; otherwise,
        //     false.
        public bool IsEmpty { get; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Adds an object to the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   item:
        //     The object to be added to the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.
        //     The value can be a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) for reference types.
        public void Add(T item);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Removes all values from the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.
        public void Clear();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Copies the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1 elements to an existing
        //     one-dimensional System.Array, starting at the specified array index.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   array:
        //     The one-dimensional System.Array that is the destination of the elements copied
        //     from the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1. The System.Array must
        //     have zero-based indexing.
        //
        //   index:
        //     The zero-based index in array at which copying begins.
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   T:System.ArgumentNullException:
        //     array is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic).
        //
        //   T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
        //     index is less than zero.
        //
        //   T:System.ArgumentException:
        //     index is equal to or greater than the length of the array -or- the number of
        //     elements in the source System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1 is greater
        //     than the available space from index to the end of the destination array.
        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int index);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns an enumerator that iterates through the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     An enumerator for the contents of the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Copies the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1 elements to a new array.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A new array containing a snapshot of elements copied from the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.
        public T[] ToArray();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Attempts to return an object from the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1
        //     without removing it.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   result:
        //     When this method returns, result contains an object from the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1
        //     or the default value of T if the operation failed.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if an object was returned successfully; otherwise, false.
        public bool TryPeek([MaybeNullWhen(false)] out T result);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Attempts to remove and return an object from the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   result:
        //     When this method returns, result contains the object removed from the System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1
        //     or the default value of T if the bag is empty.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if an object was removed successfully; otherwise, false.
        public bool TryTake([MaybeNullWhen(false)] out T result);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a compilable repro? [I don't see any issue with `IEnumerable<string?>`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mOLjvZ)

Comment: Please see Edit #1

Comment: Can you share your model design about `ConcurrentBag` and `QueuedRequest`?

Comment: Hi @XinranShen please see edit #2.

Comment: Sounds like you should have a [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-6.0) instead of a ConcurrentBag. That will help you rewrite this in a more-effective way with probably a lot less code that avoids the issue altogether.